# Docker ASP.net 5 beta4 kestrel doesn't keep container running

Tags: asp.net, docker

I was playing with [ASP.net 5 beta 4 docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/microsoft/aspnet/).
I am running the container with the entrypoint `dnx /app kestrel`.
The Dockerfile is standard from tutorials:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-beta4
MAINTAINER "xxxx" <xxxx>

#this contains project.json etc
COPY ./app /app 

WORKDIR /app

RUN ["dnu", "restore"]

EXPOSE 5004

ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "/app", "kestrel"]
```

The container starts and exits immediately, the logs for the container shows:
"Started" which indicates that there were no errors starting kestrel.

The docker command I used was `docker run -d -p "5004:5004" my_asp_net_5_docker_image:1.0.0`

What intrigues me is that if I run the container with a pseudo-tty, by doing

```
docker run -t -i -p "5004:5004" --entrypoint="/bin/bash" my_asp_net_5_docker_image:1.0.0
```

and then when I am inside the docker container I run the entrypoint command manually `dnx /app kestrel`, kestrel starts, the output is "Started" and it remains alive, and I can access the HelloWorld website successfully.
I wonder why this difference of behaviour. Why doesn't `dnx /app kestrel`
keep the container alive when I run it in the entrypoint but it does when I run it from inside the container.

UPDATE: 
I found something interesting [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/commit/95b1997c14bb6fb7e2e68dd156f4feee3d139fec)
This is a change in asp.net git hub that says "Don't require a TTY on Unix." there was a line after "Started" that did a Console.ReadLine(), it could be that this code still be in the asp.net docker image therefore it only works with tty...

UPDATE 2:
I can get it working by opening stdin (-i): `docker run -d -i -p "5004:5004" my_asp_net_5_docker_image:1.0.0`
Which suggests that the Console.ReadLine() could be the issue. This solves the problem for me now, but I don't think we should have to use -i to get the container running.

Comment: After you run the original command (only -d -p), what is the output of `docker ps`?

Comment: When I do "docker ps" no containers are running. If I do docker ps -a the container is there and status is "Exited" which could be from my theory of the git hub fix that appShutdownService.RequestShutdown(); has been called after Console.ReadLine()

Comment: `docker events` should show why it exited

Comment: from docker events I got:
2015-06-03T10:13:43.000000000+01:00 a427e1: (from my_asp_net_5_docker_image:1.0.0) create

2015-06-03T10:13:46.000000000+01:00 a427e1: (from my_asp_net_5_docker_image:1.0.0) start

2015-06-03T10:15:26.000000000+01:00 a427e1: (from my_asp_net_5_docker_image:1.0.0) die

the container dies and nothing else shows in the events